# How to Add autoincrement column to a existing snowflake table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a incremental load table and team wants to have a column which increments when each row is generated.

What have I done so far:

Step 1: To test, I have cloned exisitng table and executed below command

Step2 :

```
ALTER TABLE EL_RAW.RA.TEST_F ADD COLUMN INCREMENTED NUMBER(38,0)  DEFAULT 0;
```

The above statement is executed. but the new column(INCREMENTED)have all 0's. How to generate a column which increments automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'DEFAULT' clause, you have to use 'AUTOINCREMENT' clause

example:

```
create table tseq(n1 number, n2 number autoincrement start 1 increment 1);

insert into tseq(n1) values (1);

insert into tseq(n1) values (10);

select * from tseq;
```

Documentation link: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table